# A problem with keeping column width in ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have own algorithm for calculating column width and want have it unchangeable,
but ag-Grid resize it! After searching docs for all available methods to achieve needed results, but not have.
I prepare this pure minimal html file to illustrate situation.
Does anyone know the right way?

```
</div>
<script charset="utf-8">
'use strict'

let gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 20,
    maxWidth: 400,
    filter: true,
    resizable: false,
    suppressSizeToFit: true,
    suppressResize: true,
    headerClass: 'fixed-size-header',
  },
  columnDefs: [
  {
    "field": "id",
    "width": 80
  },
  {
    "field": "name",
    "width": 350
  },
  {
    "field": "created_at",
    "width": 140
  },
  {
    "field": "updated_at",
    "width": 140
  }
],
rowData: [
  {"id": 1,
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "created_at": "2020-04-22 10:32:13 UTC",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-22 10:32:13 UTC"
  },
  {"id": 2,
    "name": "Algebra",
    "created_at": "2020-04-22 10:32:13 UTC",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-22 10:32:13 UTC"
  } ]};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#GridDiv');
  new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `flex: 1`. The definition for setting the `flex` property is:

> Used instead of width when the goal is to fill the remaining empty
> space of the grid

Remove the `flex: 1` from your `defaultColDef`.

See [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-width).